# Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, exception, firebase-app-check

[image]

My Flutter app works fine but when the user wants to delete the account I get this error. The code works, but after a while this error appears. I did some research and found out that I needed to add appcheck. It did not work.  (Android Application)

```
main.dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity
  );
app>build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity")
}
pubspec.yaml
firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+2
```

Where am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance.

There is internet, the problem is not related to the internet.Not related to Firebase rules